# How to send alert email when Flask web service is down

Tags: flask

We have used the Flask creating a web service listening to a webhook POST request. We would like to setup a email alerting system if and only if the flask web service has somehow stopped running. We do not wanna the email been sent if the returned status code is `400` or `500`, we dont care, only when the flask application or the process has been killed.

The web service is running in the server which will never been down. Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/arlowhite/process-watcher

Comment: this repo is fantastic, very amazing. Thank you so much Harshal!

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be the flask application's responsibility. You should configure a monitoring (and alerting) system that polls the flask application and notifies you if it's unavailable.

I tend to create a `/healthz` endpoint which I don't expose to the public (it returns HTTP 200 with `ok` in response body). Then I configure polling via some monitoring system which alerts me if the poll failed.

Do you already have some kind of monitoring for your infrastructure/other services?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer first. I do think this is not a Flask app responsibility. I was originally thinking monitoring the pid?  Would you mind sharing more details in your approach? I do think we have an monitoring system yet. Do you have any recommendation concerning that?

Comment: The web service is only for listening webhooks, and then perform some operations based on the content in the POST request received. So I should make sure the service is not down. If it is down, then we will get alert ASAP. Thank you!!!! :)

Comment: PID monitoring might be the simplest solution, but it's the least precise one. If your webhooks have external dependencies (i.e: write to disk, insert into mysql) and one of those dependencies fail (i.e: disk is full, mysql connection fails) you won't notice it (your process will still be running, but webhooks will fail).

`/healthz` can check these dependencies and raise an error if any of them fails, which will trigger an alert. PID monitoring might be the best choice if you don't want to receive an alert in this case.

Comment: I'm happy to suggest a monitoring system if you need. In that case please provide some details about your infrastructure (services are plain unix process/docker containers/etc).